# Access to pubspec.yaml attributes (version) from Dart app

Tags: dart

Is there any way to access some of the attributes listed in a pubspec.yaml file in that files Dart application?

In particular, the version and description attributes may be quite useful to see in a version info dialog, or even a '--version' when using a console app. I haven't been able to find a way to access in the API. I'm not sure if Mirrors would have anything appropriate, but if a web app is compiled to JS, then I don't see the description anywhere in the output JS.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
feature request: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18769

Comment: I haven't seen anything along those lines. I would suggest you make a feature request at dartbug.com . I find this a quite interesting idea.

Comment: Will do. Thanks, Günter.

Comment: You need to suggest this to Flutter, not Dart.

Comment: @PeteAlvin I don't think flutter existed when this question was asked

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can install the "dart_config" package and use this code to parse a pubspec.yaml file:

```dart
import 'package:dart_config/default_server.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  Future<Map> conf = loadConfig("../pubspec.yaml");
  conf.then((Map config) {
    print(config['name']);
    print(config['description']);
    print(config['version']);
    print(config['author']);
    print(config['homepage']);
    print(config['dependencies']);
  });
}
```

The output looks similar to this:

```
test_cli
A sample command-line application
0.0.1
Robert Hartung
URL
{dart_config: any}
```

**EDIT**

You can do it with the Yaml package itself:

*NOTE: this will not work on Flutter Web

```dart
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';
import 'dart:io'; // *** NOTE *** This will not work on Flutter Web

void main() {      
    File f = new File("../pubspec.yaml");
    f.readAsString().then((String text) {
      Map yaml = loadYaml(text);
      print(yaml['name']);
      print(yaml['description']);
      print(yaml['version']);
      print(yaml['author']);
      print(yaml['homepage']);
      print(yaml['dependencies']);
    });
}
```

Regards Robert

Comment: The 'dart_config' solution should work out great. Many thanks for the heads-up on that, Robert.

Comment: @Robert is there any good way to unit test either of these solutions?

Comment: But can you read pubspec.yaml using this method inside a Flutter application

Comment: dart_config is now obsolete, Dart 2 incompatible.

Answer (score 47):

**FOR FLUTTER ONLY**

***Please use this new package [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) from flutter community.***

```
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

##### BELOW SOLUTION IS DEPRICATED.

I know the OP wants to read `YAML` but for flutter dev's you guys can read the version and other info of the application using <s>[package_info](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/package_info)</s>.

This is the sample to fetch details from **Android/iOS** application.

```
import 'package:package_info/package_info.dart';

PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

Comment: I agree with you. But, I have given the disclaimer that, this is for flutter, devs to read the version and other info. Don't take me wrong. I do follow the StackOverflow Guidelines :)

Comment: Sorry for my downvote, but I agree with @AndreCytryn The question is about reading the pubspec.yaml attributes, not to get package info

Comment: thank you @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6566310/jawand-singh 
You have given the perfect required answer from the perspective of Flutter Developer.  
this Answer needs to vote up :)

Comment: If you want your app working on Web, Android and IOS use "Package info_plus" 
instead. https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus.

Comment: @AlexCorreia Please post your comment as an answer so it can be upvoted. The other solutions requiring access to the file are not valid for web.

Answer (score 23):

None of the above answers worked for me, but here's a working solution for a **Flutter** app:

In your pubspec.yaml add the "pubspec.yaml" to assets:

```
assets:
  - assets/
  - pubspec.yaml
```

If you have a widget where you need to show the app version like this:

```
...
Container(
  child: Text('Version: 1.0.0+1'),
),
...
```

Wrap your widget with a FutureBuilder like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

...
        FutureBuilder(
            future: rootBundle.loadString("pubspec.yaml"),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              String version = "Unknown";
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                var yaml = loadYaml(snapshot.data);
                version = yaml["version"];
              }

              return Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Version: $version'
                ),
              );
            }),
...
```

The services [rootBundle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/rootBundle.html) property contains the resources that were packaged with the application when it was built.

If you want to show the version without the build number, you can split the string like so:

```
'Version: ${version.split("+")[0]}'
```

**UPDATE:** As mentioned by @wildsurfer, this approach has a potential security risk in web development because the pubspec.yaml is shared with the browser!

Comment: Your suggestion is really good. A more simple approach, without the need of use a 3rd party package :)

Comment: Be aware that when you do it this way in flutter web application your pubspec.yml file will be fetched by browser. This is a potential security risk.

Comment: perfect and simple way , it works nicely , great job

Comment: It works on Windows too

Answer (score 8):

So assuming that this is for a dart cli application then the @Robert suggestion won't work.

dart_config isn't available for dart 2.x and your pubspec.yaml isn't going to be relative to your cwd except when you are in your development environment

So you need to get the pubspec.yaml relative to the libraries executable path.

This example uses the 'paths' package but it isn't required.

This can be obtained by:

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart'; 

String pathToYaml =  join(dirname(Platform.script.toFilePath()), '../pubspec.yaml');
```

You can now read the yaml:

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart'; 
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

String pathToYaml = join(dirname(Platform.script.toFilePath()), '../pubspec.yaml');

File f = new File(pathToYaml);
String yamlText =   f.readAsStringSync();
      Map yaml = loadYaml(yamlText);
      print(yaml['name']);
      print(yaml['description']);
      print(yaml['version']);
      print(yaml['author']);
      print(yaml['homepage']);
      print(yaml['dependencies']);
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

You can access `pubspec.yaml` properties with the official [`pubspec_parse`](https://pub.dev/packages/pubspec_parse) package from the Dart team.

```
dart pub add pubspec_parse
```

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:pubspec_parse/pubspec_parse.dart';

final pubspec = File('pubspec.yaml').readAsStringSync();
final parsed = Pubspec.parse(pubspec);
```

You can then access typed properties on the `parsed` object.

You can find supported properties here: https://pub.dev/documentation/pubspec_parse/latest/pubspec_parse/Pubspec-class.html.

Comment: The best answer, love this official API.

Comment: Will this work on web without exposing the pubspec.yaml?

Comment: @MartinBraun yes, pubspec_parse is web compatible. I'm not sure about exposing the pubspec to the application while hiding it from the public.

Answer (score 3):

**For Flutter only (`Web`, `Android` and `IOS`)... since October 2020**

If you want your app working on **`Web`**, `Android` and `IOS` use "[Package info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus)" instead.

Answer (score 1):

## How to Incorporate Automated Version Information into A Dart Command Line App

To update version information in your code without having to package a resource file to be parsed during run time, you can have the information hard coded into an automatically generated dart source file which gets compiled into your binary.  The following example hard codes the version, name, and description information into the Map object "meta" in a `meta.dart` file. The `meta.dart` file is recreated and overwritten every time the test suite is run in development. To verify the source code has the correct version information, the app's code verifies the version and other meta information against the attributes in the pubspec.yaml file (but only when run as interpreted code in development). If there is a difference from pubspec.yaml, it throws an exception. Once compiled into a binary, it will skip that check as it won't find the pubspec.yaml file, so no error is thrown from the binary. Even if a pubspec.yaml file happens to be around and is found, it only throws an exception and does not create a "meta.dart" source file.

### 1. Create a MetaUpdate class and save it as "meta_update.dart":

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';
import 'meta.dart';

class MetaUpdate {
  String pathToYaml = "";
  String metaDartFileContents = "";
  MetaUpdate(this.pathToYaml);

  void writeMetaDartFile(String metaDartFilePath) {
    File metaDartFile = File(metaDartFilePath);

    String metaDartFileContents = """
/// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE EXCEPT TO ENTER INITIAL VERSION AND OTHER META INFO 
/// THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY OVER WRITTEN BY MetaUpdate 

Map<String, String> meta = <String, String>{
  "name": "${getPubSpec('name')}",
  "description":
      // ignore: lines_longer_than_80_chars
      "${getPubSpec('description')}",  
  "version":"${getPubSpec('version')}",
};
  """;

    metaDartFile.writeAsStringSync(metaDartFileContents);
  }

  String getPubSpec(String pubSpecParam) {
    File f = File(pathToYaml);

    String yamlText = f.readAsStringSync();
    // ignore: always_specify_types
    Map yaml = loadYaml(yamlText);

    return yaml[pubSpecParam];
  }

  void verifyLatestVersionFromPubSpec() {
    try {
      File f = File(pathToYaml);
      //exit if no pubspec found so no warning in production
      if (!f.existsSync()) return;
      //compare meta.dart with pubspec meta and give warning if difference
      if (meta.keys
          .where((dynamic e) => (meta[e] != getPubSpec(e)))
          .isNotEmpty) {
        throw Exception(
            """Version number and other meta attributes in code are different from pubspec.yaml.  Please check pubspec.yaml and then run test so that MetaUpdate can update meta information in code, then recompile""");
      }
    } on Exception {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

### 2.  Create a "meta.dart" file:

```
/// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE EXCEPT TO ENTER INITIAL VERSION AND OTHER META INFO 
/// THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY OVER WRITTEN BY MetaUpdate 

Map<String, String> meta = <String, String>{
  "name": "Acme Transmogrifier",
  "description":      
      "The best dart application ever.",  
  "version":"2021.09.001",
};
```

When you initially create the `meta.dart` file, copy your specific info from pubspec.yaml. This will later be overwritten each time your MetaUpdate.writeMetaDartFile() is run, changing the contents whenever the info in pubspec.yaml is changed.

### 3. Implement The Version Update In Your Test Code

Add the following in the first line of Main() in your test code (not the source of the main program, we don't want it to be compiled into the binary), changing the path to meta.dart as appropriate:

```
MetaUpdate("pubspec.yaml").writeMetaDartFile("lib/src/meta.dart");
```

#### 4. Add A Meta Check To Your Main Code

Put this in your app's code so it is one of the first methods executed when your app is run - it will generate an exception if there is a difference between the attributes shown in the meta.dart and pubspec.yaml:

```
    MetaUpdate("pubspec.yaml").verifyLatestVersionFromPubSpec();
```

#### 5. Using

- Make sure the Name, Version, and Description information in pubspec.yaml contains the latest information you want reflected in your code.
- Import "meta.dart" and insert meta['name'], meta['version'], etc. where you need them to be shown (e.g., in --help or --version messages to be printed to the console).
- As long as you run your tests before compiling your code the meta information will be accurately reflected in your code.