# Read pubspec.yaml from dart code in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to get access to the `pubspec.yaml` and read its properties from dart code in my `Flutter` application, while the application is running. How can I do so?

PS: I want to read the `name`, `description` and `version` properties from the pubspec during the application runtime!

Comment: this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23613637/5315089

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to pubspec.yaml attributes (version) from Dart app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613279/access-to-pubspec-yaml-attributes-version-from-dart-app)

Comment: @patreu22 This is not a duplicate as my question is that can you read the pubspec.yaml inside a Flutter application. Parsing the file on its own is not big deal, but do you have the access to it while a flutter app is running?

Comment: Hey @GurleenSethi - please try to read the link again, the mentioned package offers exactly the feature you need, so yeah that should work

Answer (score 2):

Just as mentioned in the comments above, the `package_info_plus` can help you achieve that. It helps you access the properties of `pubspec.yaml` during runtime.

- https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus
- Duplicate of [Access to pubspec.yaml attributes (version) from Dart app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613279/access-to-pubspec-yaml-attributes-version-from-dart-app/23613637#23613637)

Answer (score 0):

Use `package_info_plus` for version number of the app