# How to access app version in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In a Flutter app there is a `version` attribute in the `pubspec.yaml` file to specify the app version.

Is it possible to access this value from dart code when building for the web ?

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23613637

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613279/access-to-pubspec-yaml-attributes-version-from-dart-app/23613637#23613637](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613279/access-to-pubspec-yaml-attributes-version-from-dart-app/23613637#23613637)

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes, but it doesn't work on the web (only Android/iOS)

Comment: @marvinIsSacul My question is specifically about the Web platform

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is now [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus)

That supports flutter for web and other platforms

### Usage

```
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

String appName = packageInfo.appName;
String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
String version = packageInfo.version;
String buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
```

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/package_info_plus_web/lib/package_info_plus_web.dart), the web implementation attempts to read package info from a specific URL "/version.json" and doesn't use the pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: I just gave this a try and while the source code might look like it is coming from `pubspec.yaml` that is where the data is coming from.  At least the version # is as that is what I was concerned with.  I'd bet the URL listed in the above comment being filled with data from `pubspec.yaml` when compiled.

Comment: Hello, Flutter generates `version.json`  based on `pubspec.yml` while you build for web.