# Access to pubspec.yaml attributes (version) from Flutter Web

Tags: flutter-web

Is there any way to access some of the attributes listed in a pubspec.yaml file on a Flutter Web App?

The question is VERY similar to [Access to pubspec.yaml attributes (version) from Dart app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613279/access-to-pubspec-yaml-attributes-version-from-dart-app)

But it is not a duplicate because the options in there all use `dart:io` which is not available on Flutter Web.

Even if it is not possible to access the yaml file directly, is there a way during build time to somehow read the values and put them inside some accesible variable?

Comment: some accesible variable ? - you mean as a global variable for the web-app itself..? If thats the case, you can use `AssetBundle` to load the some config variables from say a `json` file.

Comment: But I need the values from the pubscpec itself.

Comment: As mentioned in the other post, looks like there is a an open issue.  If the information needed from pubspec.yaml file is not much, I would add an asset json and read from them. A nasty idea would be expose your pubspec.yaml itself as an asset and read using `AssetBundle`, definitely not recommended.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app working on `Web`, `Android` and `IOS` use "[Package info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus)".

The installation and examples of the mentioned package are self-explained.

However, here is a brief excerpt showing how to get the name of the app from `pubspec.yaml` to `_appName` String:

```
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

...

class ConfigScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ConfigScreenState createState() => _ConfigScreenState();
}

class _ConfigScreenState extends State<ConfigScreen> {

  ...

  String _appName = 'Unknown';

  void _initPackageInfo() {
    PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      setState(() {
        _appName = packageInfo.appName;
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _initPackageInfo();
    super.initState();
  }


  //Now, you can use the String _appName to print its content inside a build method of the StatefulWidget.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('App name: ${_appName}'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```