# Get version from pubspec for web in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

There's the `package_info` package to get the version of your application from pubspec.yaml file on mobiles (Android/iOS). I'm looking for a similar package for web. All the solutions I've found so far are not applicable for web.

Is there a way to obtain version from pubspec.yaml in Flutter app for web?

My `pubspec.yaml`. I wanted to display 1.0.4 as a Widget.

```
name: web
description: client's webpage
version: 1.0.4
...
```

Comment: Try [Access to pubspec.yaml attributes (version) from Dart app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613279/access-to-pubspec-yaml-attributes-version-from-dart-app)

Comment: @dev-aentgs are you sure this works for web? I've tried the code posted in the link and it doesn't work for me. That question is for pure Dart, my is about web Flutter app

Comment: i am not sure, thought the edited part of answer might work(since it worked directly with yaml file, i thought it might work for you for reading contents of the `pubspec.yaml` file). Referring to the Edit section of answer containing  `import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';`

Comment: You were right. Tried it out it doesn't work, `dart:io` file operations aren't accessible to web applications.

Comment: @dev-aentgs exactly that's the main reason why parsing yaml file is not an option for web

Comment: Use "package_info_plus" (https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) and your app's version info is going to work on Web, Android and IOS.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, [package_info_plus_web](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus_web) is available for web implementation. But it seems that this package is already included as part of the [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) package dependency, and will be included when using [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) as normal.